# Send emails using JavaMail from my own domain in AWS

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, dns, smtp, jakarta-mail

We have been sending email notifications (outbound only) to our customers using a gmail address **donotreply@gmail.com** and we got smtp host and port configured in our server.

Now we would like to send these emails with our domain name i.e **donotreply@mycompanydomain.com**

Our site is hosted on AWS and we bought our domain from **dyn.com**, is there way it can be done using AWS SES or dyn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I registered to https://sendgrid.com/ and their email relay helped me to send from any name from my domain. The domain verification process was also manual and very simple.

Amazon SES will be a good fit for large scale projects where we need lot of emails, also it takes some time to get used to SES configurations, "sendgrid" being easy and free I proceeded with that.

Comment: Not sure who downgraded it, please give logical explanation before downgrading answers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with proper DNS configuration you can use Simple Email Service to do this. You will need to either (1) be able to monitor inbound submissions to the company domain or (2) [set up and use SNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/best-practices-bounces-complaints.html) for bounces, though.

[Here are setup details](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/setting-up-ses.html). Note there's a "dev" and a "production" mode. "dev" means you can only send from and send to preapproved addresses. It's perfectly fine for learning how to use it.

You can use [javamail](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-smtp-java.html) or you can use the [AWS Java SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-java.html).

Comment: Thank you @tedder42 , for our use case I felt sendgrid is a better choice.